# EventHub PartitionContext Class Design

Tags: c#, azure, unit-testing, azure-eventhub

I am trying to test my implementation of the IEventProcessor. However, I am having a hard time, because it is impossible to actually mock the PartitionContext class (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.partitioncontext.aspx).

For example, I can not verify if the CheckpointAsync() method has been called correctly, because the ICheckpointer interface is internal and the actual method is not virtual.
Furthermore, I can not inject my own ICheckpointManager instance, because the constructor which allows this, is internal.

What is the design decisions in making everything internal, which would allow me to mock this class?

Either this is really bad design or I am missing something.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is a lot of work to test this. Here's what to do.

So you create a wrapper:

```
public interface ICheckPointer
{
    Task CheckpointAsync(PartitionContext context);
}

public class CheckPointer : ICheckPointer
{
    public Task CheckPointAsync(PartitionContext context)
    {
        return context.CheckpointAsync();
    }
}
```

In your unit test method you can now mock the interface and check whether `CheckPointAsync` is called.

Your implementation of `IEventProcessor` now should accept an instance of `ICheckPointer`:

```
public class SampleEventProcessor : IEventProcessor
{
    private ICheckPointer checkPointer;

    public SampleEventProcessor(ICheckPointer checkPointer)
    {
        this.checkPointer = checkPointer;
    }

    public Task OpenAsync(PartitionContext context)
    {
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public async Task ProcessEventsAsync(PartitionContext context, IEnumerable<EventData> events)
    {
        ...

        await checkPointer.CheckpointAsync(context);
    }

    public async Task CloseAsync(PartitionContext context, CloseReason reason)
    {
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
}
```

You will need an implementation of `IEventProcessorFactory` to inject the `ICheckPoint` interface:

```
internal class SampleEventProcessorFactory : IEventProcessorFactory
{
    private readonly ICheckPointer checkPointer;

    public SampleEventProcessorFactory (ICheckPointer checkPointer)
    {
        this.checkPointer = checkPointer;
    }

    public IEventProcessor CreateEventProcessor(PartitionContext context)
    {
        return new SampleEventProcessor(checkPointer);
    }
}
```

and you create the EventProcessor like this:

```
await host.RegisterEventProcessorFactoryAsync(new SampleEventProcessor(new CheckPointer()));
```

in the unit test you could now do something like (based on NSubstitute):

```
var mock = Substitute.For<ICheckPointer>();
var sample = new SampleEventProcessor(mock);
await sample.ProcessEventsAsync(new PartitionContext(), null);
mock.Received().CheckPointAsync(Arg.Any<PartitionContext>());
```

Warning: did not compile the code so there could be some syntax errors. At least it should give you a basic idea of how to proceed.

Comment: "new PartitionContext()" causes a compilation error because the constructor is apparently not public.

Comment: @Dudeman3000 It was at the time the question is posted, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.partitioncontext.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_PartitionContext__ctor). What NuGet package are you using?

Comment: Apologies, I'm working with the PartitionContext in the Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.Processor namespace. I'm using NuGet package v2.0.1. Looking at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.eventhubs.processor.partitioncontext?view=azure-dotnet-legacy&viewFallbackFrom=azure-dotnet) it appears that there is no version that offers a public empty constructor. I've attempted to use the available constructor but was unable to mock or instantiate the required EventProcessorHost parameter.

Answer (score 2):

A fairly new addition to the `Azure.Messaging.EventHubs` library is `EventHubsModelFactory`, it has some helpful static methods for unit testing.

```
ParitionContext partitionCtx = EventHubsModelFactory.PartitionContext(partitionId);
```

Comment: Hi W. Poust, thanks for your post. Can you update your answer explaining more clearly how this answers the original question?